# onPaste not recognized as event by HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, onpaste

I'm in the middle of making a user registration form and want to prevent pasting into certain input boxes. Problem is, onPaste isn't being recognized as an event.
As you can see in this image, onKeyPress is being recognized, whereas onPaste is not.
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FD5l.png]

After some Googling it seems I am the only person on the planet who has encountered this (which probably means it's something silly and I'm a massive idiot). I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot wrong with the clipBoard API at the moment: https://caniuse.com/#search=paste

Comment: Why would you punish people using password managers? Preventing people to paste passwords is really something you shouldn't do. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131106/is-there-any-reason-to-disable-paste-password-on-login

Comment: Maybe it's your IDE not recognizing `onpaste` event? Browsers mainly support it quite widely, as you can see behind randy's link. Btw. the image doesn't tell anything about "recognizing" onpaste event to those who are not familiar with the IDE, which's name you haven't included in the post ...

Comment: If there is an issue, providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, would help a lot. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apologies, I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 (I'll edit the post to include this). onPaste is being treated like it's a non-event attribute. Thanks Ivar duly noted; I'm fairly new to web design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! As I suspected, I was being a massive idiot. onPaste doesn't *appear* to be recognized as an event in my IDE, but on run-time it will actually fire. My JavaScript code for the event was flawed and this is why nothing was happening.

Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onpaste` instead of  `onPaste` as it shows on the [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) example page. and what is the IDE are you using? try using a different syntax highlighting add-in or a plugin.

Comment: W3Schools is **not** affiliated with W3C. ([And is often considered a bad resource.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com))

Comment: Same result unfortunately. I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 but also tried it on Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function preventPasting(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<input type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="password" onpaste="preventPasting(this.id)">
```

Change 'onPaste' with 'onpaste', maybe like this code.

For more documentation of onpaste : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp